# how do I make a 2d array function

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a function that makes a 2d array but I have a syntax error
here is the function

```
function asdf(col,row)
{
    let arr = new Array(col);
    let i = 0;
    for (i < col; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new Array(row);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

the error is at the ")" at the end of the for loop
any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to a missing semi-colon in the for loop:

```
for (i < col; i++)
```

Change it to

```
for (;i < col; i++)
```

A better approach can be just to simply define the loop variable in the `for` loop like so:

```
for (let i = 0;i < col; i++)
```

Comment: A good catch, but clearer to recommend standard syntax `for (let i = 0; i < col; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

The for statement creates a loop with 3 optional expressions:

```
for (expression 1; expression 2; expression 3) {
  // code block to be executed
}
```

Expression 1 is executed (one time) before the execution of the code block.

Expression 2 defines the condition for executing the code block.

Expression 3 is executed (every time) after the code block has been executed.

There's a syntax error because you are missing Expression 1.